# Get variance components for each level of a random factor in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Using the sleepstudy dataset as an example, if I run the following code I can obtain the variance component for the random factor in this model, 'Subject'.

```
data("sleepstudy")
model<-lmer(Reaction~Days + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
print(VarCorr(model),comp=c("Variance"))
 #Groups   Name        Variance
 #Subject  (Intercept) 1378.18 
 #Residual              960.46
```

But what if I wanted to know the variance attributable to Subject 308 vs Subject 370 etc? Is this possible?

I think I see [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/genotype-experiments-fitting-a-stability-variance-model-with-r/) that it is possible in `nlme`, but is there an `lme4` solution?

Comment: It might be `arm::se.ranef()` that you're looking for, is there any reason you can't fit your model using `nlme`?

Comment: I don't think ```arm::se.ranef()``` is what I'm looking for - all the SEs are the same, and you can get the same info from ```as.data.frame(ranef(model)```. Yes I probably could do it in ```nlme```, but I'm much more familiar with and have done all the other bits of this analysis using ```lme4```, so was just hoping for an ```lme4``` solution to fit into my existing models, rather than have to figure out ```nlme``` and re-do everything :)

Comment: I'm even more confused by what you're looking for now - `ranef(model)` gives random effect predictions (i.e. conditional means), `arm::se.ranef(model)` their standard error (assuming this is what you meant by "variance attributable to subject") - the latter is indeed also extracted from `attr(ranef, "condVar")` by `as.data.frame`. As with almost all mixed implementations there is some empirical Bayes shrinkage in their calculation. Either way, the latter is the conditional random effect variance. The fact that it's the same for all subjects is a product of the model/example you've provided.

Comment: Hmm okay - between your comment and re-reading that nlme example I posted a link to, I think it's because I have to specify the random effects differently to obtain a model with an appropriate variance-covariance matrix to get different variances for each level of the random factor. I will go and do some more reading ... thanks!